# setMonth(1) gives me March?

Tags: javascript

Why is setMonth(1) giving me March? I believe that 0=Jan, 1=Feb, 2=Mar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = init;

function init(){
var d = new Date();
d.setFullYear(2014);
d.setMonth(1);
d.setDate(1);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I get...

Sat Mar 01 2014 15:11:03 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

I'm running Win7 Pro 64-bit and the clock and calendar seem to be correct.

Comment: It works for me. `Sat Feb 01 2014 01:28:52`

Comment: Check this [StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14680430/3255431)

Comment: I think it's because it's the 31st and it adds 30 days (mine is just a supposition based on nothing :) )

Comment: @Givi, really? I get Sat Mar 01 2014

Comment: Reverse your setDate and setMonth.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't think it matters since `d.setMonth(1)` already evaluates to March, since today is the 31st. The setDate line simply sets the date of March to 1st

Comment: @Bic — That works in this case, but not in the general case because you might want to set it to the 31st of March when it is the 28th of Feb.

Comment: @putvande maybe it's works for me, because at my time zone is already 1th february?

Comment: possible duplicate of [the Date.getMonth() method has bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680396/the-date-getmonth-method-has-bug)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Today is the 31st of January. When you `d.setMonth(1);` you are trying to set the date to the 31st of February. Since this date doesn't exist, it falls over to the 3rd of March.

Set the whole date when you initialise the object, don't try to change it piecemeal.

Comment: [_If you do not specify the dayValue parameter, the value returned from the getDate method is used._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)

Comment: Or you could set the date first to avoid the 31-day issue: d.setFullYear(2014); d.setDate(1); d.setMonth(1);

Comment: @BrettFromLA — That just gives you the reverse problem when you want to set the 31st of January when it is the 28th of Feb.

Comment: @Quentin Good point! I'd added an answer, which was to set the whole date when you initialize the object, but since it was a solution instead of an explanation it got 2 down-votes right away. So I deleted it. :P