# Why this datetime funtion setMonth result is wrong? getMonth() + 1

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, object, date-formatting

I have this code:

```
var nextDate  = new Date("2016 01 31");
nextDate.setMonth(nextDate.getMonth() + 1);
```

I'm expecting the result to be `Feb 28 2016`, but it shows `Mar 02 2016` instead.

Why? Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490366/setmonth1-gives-me-march And some explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14680430/5119765

Comment: In Safari, `new Date("2016 01 31")` returns an invalid date, so your first issue is to correctly parse the string.

Answer (score 0):

This is because February has 29 days, and when you set new month from January, which has 31 day, to February then the difference of the days are transferred to another month.
Easy way to do it is just create new Date instance.

You might need to implement some logic to get corresponding dates right

Answer (score 0):

There is only 29 day in February, therefore, February 31 February will translate to Mars 2.

You need to update the days in your date object to the last day of that month. You can get the last day of the month by specifying a function that sets the date to 0:

```js
function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible work around with a helper function: after `setMonth`, check if the results doesn't contain a month equal to the expected month and if so, use `setDate(0)`, which sets the date to last day of the previous month. e.g.

```js
Date.prototype.addMonths = function(months){
  var m = this.getMonth() + (months || 1);  
  this.setMonth(m);   
  if(this.getMonth() !== (m % 11)) //11: month is 0 based
   this.setDate(0);   
}


var nextDate  = new Date("2016 01 31");
nextDate.addMonths(1);
document.writeln(nextDate);
```

`months || 1` only is meant to have a default value if no month was submitted. `m % 11` is needed in case of year transitions. 11 and not 12 because javascripts month (and thus `getMonth`) is 0 based.