# Confuse about setUTC in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

All:

The time I wrote this question is:

Mon Oct 31 2016 10:19:01 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

There is one thing about setUTCDate which confuses me, I want to build a Date Object to June 01 2016 00:00:00:000 from current time, so I did this:

1. `var dt = new Date();` // this step, it shows: Mon Oct 31 2016 10:19:01 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
2. `dt.setUTCMonth(5);` **// this step, it shows: Wed Jul 01 2016 10:19:01 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) which I do not understand, why it is not Jun 30 2016 10:19:01 GMT-0700?**
3. `dt.setUTCDate(1);`

Thanks

Comment: Hint: How many days are there in June?

Comment: @JJJ sorry, I mean why it is not Jun 30

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the Date.getMonth() method has bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680396/the-date-getmonth-method-has-bug) (doesn't have anything to do with UTC specifically)

Comment: @JJJ Ok, I get it, now I know how Date operate time more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you are starting from the date Oct. 31. If you then set the month to 5, then this is equivalent to trying to change the date to June 31. Since no such date exists, it adjusts to July 1.

But if you want to create a `Date` object for June 1, 2016, then just create one:

```
var d  = new Date(2016, 5, 1);           // June 1, 2016, 12AM local time
var d2 = new Date(Date.UTC(2016, 5, 1)); // June 1, 2016, 12AM UTC
```