# Subtracting months from current date is returning unexpected results. Same Month (March) is being returned twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I have created a method that returns the past months according to the current date and how many months from the past you need, seems like the javascript date object is
behaving wrongly.

I guess the problem has only popped up today as it's the 29th of the current month and subtracting 1 month from `29 March`  which is supposed to be `29 February` (doesn't exist) lead javascript to fallback to +1 day...

Can someone please suggest a great fix for this.
Thanks

```
export type Config = {
  n: number;
  i18n: i18n;
};

export default function NMonthsAgo(config: Config): MonthsAgo[] {
  const date = new Date();
  const { i18n } = config;
  let { n } = config;
  n = Math.max(n, 0);
  // add one month in future to include the current one.
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  return Array.from({ length: n || 1 })
    .map(() => {
      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
      console.log(date.toDateString()); ===> console print.
      return {
        monthName: formatDate(i18n, date, { month: 'long' }),
        monthNameShort: formatDate(i18n, date, { month: 'short' }),
        year: formatDate(i18n, date, { year: 'numeric' }),
      };
    })
    .reverse();
}
```

**Output:**

```
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Wed Dec 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Mon Nov 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Fri Oct 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Wed Sep 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Sun Aug 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Thu Jul 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Tue Jun 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Sat May 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Thu Apr 29 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Mon Mar 29 2021 <=== Mars is returned twice... 
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Mon Mar 01 2021 <=== Mars is returned twice...
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Mon Feb 01 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Fri Jan 01 2021
NMonthsAgo.js:36 Wed Dec 29 2021
```

Comment: If you subtract one month from the 29th March, what result do you expect to get back? Your code is trying to return a date of the 29th Feb so the library is doing the best it can with the bad inputs.

Comment: Check this answer if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14680430/10048850. And I would suggest using `moment`, `dayjs`, or any other library that works with dates. Plus your current code doesn't account for a year shift, you have `Wed Dec 29 2021` as the last record, but it should be 2020.